# Why can i not login to the wso2 api store using the email address of a secondary user store account

Tags: wso2-api-manager

## Problem

I am trying to login to our API store using an account from a secondary user store, every attempt results in the following error

> Error! Login failed. Please recheck the username and password and try again.

## Debugging

#### what seems to works

I can make an account on the primary store,
username: fred@text.com 
password: password

This user can login without a problem.

The secondary user store is a JDBC connection pointing at our Oracle database, called storeTwo.
I can see the users, totaling 49,000, in the carbon management interface, along with the roles they have.
I have given a subset of these users every permission possible.

#### what doesn't work

When I take one of these accounts and try to login, I get the error mentioned above.

I cannot tell what the issues here are.

To me, it looks like wso2 isn't checking the secondary store when I try and login.

## Other info

- server OS: Centos 6
- wso2 version: 2.1.0
- wso2 info: standalone setup of wso2 API Manager.

### config files

#### storeTwo.xml

```
  <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP>:<HOST></Property>
    <Property name="userName"><user></Property>
    <Property encrypted="true" name="password"><pasword></Property>
    <Property name="driverName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</Property>
    <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated.</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password pattern policy violated.</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="CaseInsensitiveUsername">true</Property>
    <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordDigest">MD5</Property>
    <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
    <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">false</Property>
    <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
    <Property name="validationQuery"/>
    <Property name="validationInterval"/>
```

#### carbon.xml

```
...
<LoginConfig>
  <UserIdLogin  primary="true">
    <ClaimUri></ClaimUri>
  </UserIdLogin>
  <EmailLogin  primary="true">
   <ClaimUri>http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress</ClaimUri>
  </EmailLogin>
</LoginConfig>
...
```

#### wso2carbon.log

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'temp@example.com[-1234]' at [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288+0100] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:loginResponse" {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  start writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    preserve=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    isOptimized=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,288] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    isDoingSWA=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,289] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils} -  createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml) {org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,289] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  end writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-20 10:59:49,290] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Login failed. Please recheck the username and password and try again. {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting up a writable secondary user store, I've have found what looks to be the root problem. when you choose MD5 for the 'Password Hashing Algorithm' WSO2 seems to do the following.

> MD5(password) -binary | base 64 = X03MO1qnZdYdgyfeuILPmQ==

whereas

> MD5(password) = 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

this would then mean that when wso2 is checking the read-only secondary store mention above the passwords will never (very rarely) match.

The last post at [1](https://forum.ahsay.com/viewtopic.php?t=7442) has an example (not for wso2) of this - below are the commands needed to test on the terminal in case link fails.

> echo -n password | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 
> echo -n password | openssl dgst -md5

[Example md5 calls](https://forum.ahsay.com/viewtopic.php?t=7442)